# Is it considered a bad habit to post more than one question on the same topic?

Tags: discussion, behavior, similar-questions, updating-questions

Let me explain better: suppose I asked a question about a problem A. 
Then, while waiting for the answer, I continued my researches about and I found a possible workaround for A, but I have some doubts about it. 
Even though the workaround is surely related to problem A, it's not exactly on the same topic and does not fully solve A.

In general I should probably edit my question adding my progresses and my actual doubts but I may still be interested in finding an answer to the original problem.

Is it considered a bad habit to post a question about the workaround?

Comment: It's a free  country, keep searching for solutions. Leave no stone unturned. Conquer all your doubts. And always, always Have a Red Bull handy. Godspeed

Comment: This question hints that your original question was not researched well enough to turn to SO before asking. We generally expect you to investigate your problems before asking us to solve them for you.

Comment: @M.Babcock Well, not necessarily; I mean, of course if someone knows the solution to problem A then there is surely a way to get to it (and from this point of view of course was not researched well enough), but I think nobody expects that I (or anybody else in my place) search for all possible solution before asking to SO. A question may also be a good way to _start_ researching. Besides, as I said, I was wondering about the fact that the second question may be _related_ to the first, but different. I'm not sure if this is considered bad habit as well as asking two times the same question...

Comment: @Saphrosit - I realize that the 2 questions aren't exact duplicates but without unabstracting your questions there is little hope to know whether it is appropriate. If the answer that led to asking question B was implied (at least to any possible answerer) as a possible answer to question A then question B is likely to be voted as a dupe. Without knowing the detail this is strictly subjective (or objective I tend to be confused by the difference).

Comment: I've always wondered about those cyclical questions on the same topic that link to each other, but neither has an answer so they both wind up in a perpetual limbo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are a programmer, so you should be able to work out if the two questions are close enough related so that question B should be included as an edit to question A, or whether it should be a separate question on its own.

If the questions are too similar then you will get people casting votes to close it as a duplicate. If you do decide to post separate questions then you could do your readers a courtesy and post a link from each question to the other, explaining that one leads on from the other. There is no problem with splitting up questions where appropriate, we like to the questions to be targeted and to the point.

If you do decide to edit the original question the edit should bump it back up to the [Active Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) tab, even if the bump is momentary, so your question should still continue to receive some attention.